# Where and/or how to generate custom android button graphic images?

Tags: android, button

I'm creating an app, and I want it to be more colorful and vivid. Though, I'm not an artist or have any drawing talent. Is there someplace online where I can create custom images for my android buttons that can save to a .png file?

I'm looking for images that make my buttons look more real than the plain, generic buttons.

I'm looking for something like this: http://www.webarti.com/best-CSS3-button-maker/ but to able to obtain a png of the final button.

Comment: Just use the CSS button generator and take a screenshot when done.

Comment: Other than any copyright issues, this seems like the best solution. Be sure to read their terms and conditions before saving a screenshot.

Comment: @Scott thats a good idea. I never even thought about that. Thanks! I'll make sure to look at there terms and conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, like you said you are not an artist I would base your design only on the given APIs, Android and iOS ones. Like the user plainclothes told you be careful on the direction you are heading. If what you want it so build a game having the same design on both platforms is not an issue at all since it's usually the pattern. But if you are dealing with an application I wouldn't do it. I would instead try to follow the design guidelines of each OS. You can find the Android Design Guidelines here: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

But if you still want to create graphics for your applications there are other problems you will face, true for both platforms but specially relevant for Android. I'm talking about dealing with multi-resolution and density screens. In order for your graphics to scale properly you will need to have different sets of graphics for different densities. On iOS this is typically two sets of graphics for each device type (iPhone, iPad, Retina and non-Retina, but I don't have much experience there so I can't actually tell you if this ir right). In terms of Android things get a bit "ouf of hand". You really need to have several resolutions of your graphic to cover all, or most of the different available devices. You can get a really good explanation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

To conclude, follow the design guidelines but in the last case just use the built-in design buttons or design your own using XML (for Android) for example.

Answer (score 1):

### You're asking for trouble

You note yourself that ...

> I'm not an artist or have any drawing talent

So I assume you probably don't have much in the way of design experience either. Why would you try to make special buttons when you don't know what you're doing?

### Here's one way to stay out of trouble

1. **Start with nice system buttons** that don't struggle too much against the norm of the OS. Building a unique interface style within another interface is a difficult task best left to experienced UI design practitioners.
2. **Identify key actions in your app** that would benefit from some kind of imagery. Keep [the concept of cognitive load](http://usabilityfriction.com/2010/11/22/cognitive-load/) in mind and find ways to ease your user's load.
3. **Find an icon set that fits the style and content of your app** and matches up with those key actions. No need to create new images on your own. If you don't have the budget to hire a designer, just [search a site like IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/).
4. **Use icons in your nice clean system buttons** to add flair to your app!

Comment: I want to make an app on both ios and android, but I want the interface for both almost excatly the same. So, all the designs and themes would be the same. With that desire, both ios and android system stock buttons are different. I want my app to colorful and to pop out to the user.

Comment: I'd be very careful with that approach. iOS users like apps that stick with the metaphor. Android users are a little more flexible.